# Go back to 'new tab' page in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I would like to have FF allow me to go back to the New Tab page, just as it allows going back to any other previous page. This is a much faster workflow for how I work with it. I know this is a [long outstanding known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776167) but I was wondering whether there really isn't a way around it, be it via an extension or developer tools or otherwise, or some other way I can get things done faster.

Current behaviour I use tens of times per day:

- create new tab
- visit website (by selecting pinned tab)
- close tab
- create new tab
- visit website
- close tab
- repeat..

What I'd like to happen instead:

- create new tab
- visit website
- go back to new tab page (back button/mouse gesture/...)
- visit website
- repeat..

Comment: Why not set `about:newtab` as your home page and just click the home button when you need to go back to it? Alternatively once you've set it as your home page you can use the relevant [keyboard shortcut](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation) to get back to it quickly.

Comment: @Mokubai clever, and actually nearly perfect (esp. after assiging a gesture to it)! Please post that as an answer and unless someone comes up with a better alternative I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I would use would be to set `about:newtab` as your home page and then just click the home button when you need to go back to it.

Alternatively once you've set it as your home page you can use the relevant [keyboard shortcut](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation)  to get back to it quickly.